# Using inferior python and tramp together

Tags: python, tramp

For the last few weeks, I decide to work directly in a remote server using tramp-mode, with great success and joy.

However, recently I decide to add python-mode and an inferior ipython3 sheel to emacs, still working with remote files via tramp. The setup mostly works, and I can run the ipython kernel from the remote servet with little problem.

However, everytime I try to send the current buffer (or region, or file) to be executed, I get the following kind of error (the filename may change to a real filename, according to the function):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/ssh:mss:/tmp/df1fefb99e7a8013d07dcc5ef8b002be-psss-temp.py
```

(mss being my server alias).

This seems to be due to python-mode sending the file path with the TRAMP ssh prefix in it. If I just erase the '/ssh:mss:', the remote iPython functions as expected.

How can I correct this? I suppose I could change python-mode code to correct for the TRAMP prefix, but I don't know where to look for changing. My emacs file, if anyone is interested is in https://github.com/aylons/emacsd/tree/master/

Answer (score 1):

Which Emacs version are you using? Reading python.el, this problem seems to have been fixed back in September 2012. I don't know which Emacs version this fix belongs to, but I guess it shall work at least for Emacs 24.3. See also this [bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12340)

Comment: I am using Emacs 24.5.1. However, I am not using python.el, but python-mode.el, which had some functions I liked. Maybe I can port the patch from the link you passed from python.el to python-mode.el. Sounds like a good start.

Comment: Well, I don't know python-mode.el. But you could also check this package for usage of `buffer-file-name`. It shall not pass the value of that variable to any shell script. Instead of, it must be checked whether the string is a remote file name, and if yes, the local file name part shall be passed only. Use `file-remote-p` for this task.